# How to render 2 child routes in same page (side by side) using react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to get a 3 column layout sidebar, inner bar, main content. the problem is inner bar and main content are both nested routes of portal so when the path changes to '/:state/:building' I get the sidebar and inner bar but when route changes again to '/:state/:building/:clientId/details' I get sidebar main Content instead of sidebar, inner bar, main Content

What I tried:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
    <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
    <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>} errorElement={<Error/>}/>
    <Route path='/reset-password' element={<ResetPassword/>} />
    <Route element={<AuthWrapper/>}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Portal/>} loader={portalLoader}>
          <Route path='/:state/:building' element={<Innerbar/>} loader={innerbarLoader}/>
          <Route path='/:state/:building/:clientId/details' element={<MainContent/>} loader={MainContentLoader}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<div>This route does not exist 404</div>}/>
    </>
  ))
```

inside of portal I have a sidebar followed by Outlet

```
<Stack
        direction="row"
        spacing={{sm: 1}}
        justifyContent="space-between"
        sx={{ height: "calc(100% - 66px)", overflow: 'hidden',  }}
      >
        <Sidebar
          openSidebar={open}
          setOpenSidebar={setOpen}
          building={data}
          isSelected={isSelected}
          setIsSelected={setIsSelected}
        />
        <Outlet/>
{/* {params.state && params.building && <Innerbar openSidebar={open} isSelected={isSelected} />}
        {params.state && params.building && params.clientId &&<MainContent />} */}

      </Stack>
```

what i'm currently getting is a sidebar click a link and the inner bar renders click a link in inner bar and main content renders but each removes the other component (the commented code is also what i tried). what I want is both on same page
any ideas how I can get this layout?

Comment: I know nothing about how React Router works, but just from a purely logical viewpoint, it seems like `<Route path='/:state/:building/:clientId/details'` should be nested under `<Route path='/:state/:building'`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey you are right i haven't thought about it....

Comment: I am a SME and I agree with @HereticMonkey, nesting `MainContent`'s route in the `Innerbar` layout route makes sense to me. Do you require assistance from here?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you, I have tested HereticMonkey solution and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As @HereticMonkey and @drewReese pointed out in the comments, MainContent should be nested within InnerBar. here's my App.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
        <>
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>} errorElement={<Error/>}/>
        <Route path='/reset-password' element={<ResetPassword/>} />
        <Route element={<AuthWrapper/>}>
          <Route path='/' element={<Portal/>} loader={portalLoader}>
              <Route path='/:state/:building' element={<Innerbar/>} loader={innerbarLoader}>
                  <Route path=':clientId/details' element={<MainContent/>} loader={MainContentLoader}/>
              </Route>
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' element={<div>This route does not exist 404</div>}/>
        </>
      ))
```

Thanks for the help!